# how to add additional object to a key that already references one or more objects?

Tags: javascript

Right now as part of my react state, I have a users key that points to at least one object, ex:

```
{  
   users:{  
      user1:{  
         key:value,
         key:value
      }
   }
}
```

or

```
{  
   users:{  
      user1:{  
         key:value,
         key:value
      }
   },
   {  
      user2:{  
         key:value,
         key:value
      }
   }
}
```

How do I add an additional value to the users key in the state object that is another user object (eg- user3)?

Comment: Assuming `var newUser = { user3: { key: 'value' } };` and `obj.users` is an array of objects (not clear from your question since your second example has syntax errors) you can use `obj.users.push( newUser );`. If `obj.users` is not an array you can use `Object.assign( obj.users, newUser );` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Using your example with an object.**

#### Add a new property as follow:

```
obj.users['user3'] = user3;
```

```js
var obj = {  users: {    user1: {      key1: 'value',      key2: 'value'    },    user2: {      key1: 'value',      key2: 'value'    }  }};

var user3 = {
  key1: 'value',
  key2: 'value'
};

obj.users['user3'] = user3;

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### Using the function `Object.assign(...)`

```
obj.users['user3'] = user3;
```

```js
var obj = {  users: {    user1: {      key1: 'value',      key2: 'value'    },    user2: {      key1: 'value',      key2: 'value'    }  }};

var user3 = {
  key1: 'value',
  key2: 'value'
};

Object.assign(obj.users, { 'user3': user3});

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### Using the Spread syntax `...`

```
obj.users['user3'] = user3;
```

```js
var obj = {  users: {    user1: {      key1: 'value',      key2: 'value'    },    user2: {      key1: 'value',      key2: 'value'    }  }};

var user3 = {
  key1: 'value',
  key2: 'value'
};

obj.users = {...obj.users, 'user3': user3};

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```